# Development Purpose Only watermark even after adding client id and key in https request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using the url as below to request the Google Maps API, and getting Developer purpose only in output. https://www.google.com/jsapi?sensor=true&libraries=places&key=**********&client=*******

Can anyone help me what is wrong with the request format. Should I use url like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&key=***********&client=*********

Tried both the urls in the request but getting development purpose only watermark on maps.

Map in the web application without any watermark.

Comment: What error message do you get in the Javascript console?

Comment: I'm getting an error of NoApiKeys

Comment: That implies that neither of the includes that you posted is correct, because they look like they include keys.  Is that the only message (maybe you are including the API multiple times)? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Although, looking at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#client-id), `client_id` replaces `key` (unless I am reading it wrong)

Comment: https://www.google.com/jsapi?sensor=true&libraries=places&key=MYPRIVATEKEY&client=CLIENTID   , I have added both in the http request. Should I remove client and other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are both using the "key" parameter for API key and "client" parameter for client ID. You should only choose one type of authentication. Using both will lead to an error, just like what you are experiencing right now.

This is the correct way to load Javascript API key:

You can learn more **[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)**.

If you have a Premium Plan license and wish to use your client instead:

This **[Detailed guide for Premium Plan customers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#premium-auth)** will be a big help to you.

Also, you don't need to the "sensor" parameter anymore.

Hope my answer helps!